# Pandas - groupby columns with conditions from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am struggling with pandas regarding how to group multiple column values with conditions:

Here is how my data looks like as a pandas dataframe:

```
id      trigger     timestamp
1       started     2017-10-01 14:00:1
1       ended       2017-10-04 12:00:1
2       started     2017-10-02 10:00:1
1       started     2017-10-03 11:00:1
2       ended       2017-10-04 12:00:1    
2       started     2017-10-05 15:00:1
1       ended       2017-10-05 16:00:1
2       ended       2017-10-05 17:00:1
```

My goal is to find the difference in day/hour or minutes between the dates grouped by the id.

My output should look more like this (diff in hrs):

```
id      trigger     timestamp           trigger     timestamp               diff
1       started     2017-10-01 14:00:1  ended       2017-10-04 12:00:1      70
1       started     2017-10-03 11:00:1  ended       2017-10-05 16:00:1      53
2       started     2017-10-02 10:00:1  ended       2017-10-04 12:00:1      26
2       started     2017-10-05 15:00:1  ended       2017-10-05 17:00:1      2
```

I have tried many options, but I can not the most efficient solution.

Here is my code until now:

First I tried to split the data in 'started' and 'ended':

```
df['started'] = df.groupby(['id', 'timestamp'])['trigger'] == 'started'

df['ended'] = df.groupby(['id', 'timestamp'])['trigger'] == 'ended'
```

and then:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'started', 'ended'], as_index=True).sum()
```

but it dind't work.
or

```
df['started'] = df.groupby(['trigger'])['timestamp'].np.where(df['trigger']=='started')
```

also without gut results.

Can some point in the right direction how to do this with pandas?
I will also have null matches in the data, how can I use `df.fillna(method='ffill')` to add NaN or missing data to the new dataframe.

Comment: You can use `df.iterrows()` or `df.itertuples()` (which is faster) to solve this problem. As for the `.fillna`, the question is not very clear, but the code you posted will forward fill values, You could do something like `df['column_name'].fillna(value=0)` to substitute `NaN` for `0` for a specific column named `column_name`.

Answer (score 9):

1. Set `id` and `trigger` as the index
2. Since the index contains duplicate entries, append another index column with the groupwise cumcount. Totally, `df` must have a `MultiIndex` with 3 columns
3. `unstack` on `timestamp`
4. Find the difference between the columns hourwise and assign the result back

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']) # if necessary

i = df.groupby(['id', 'trigger']).cumcount()
df.set_index(['id', i, 'trigger']).timestamp.unstack().assign(
       diff=lambda d: d.ended.sub(d.started).dt.total_seconds() / 3600
)
```

Thanks to piRSquared for the improvement.

```
v

                  timestamp                      diff
trigger               ended             started      
id                                                   
1  0    2017-10-04 12:00:01 2017-10-01 14:00:01  70.0
   1    2017-10-05 16:00:01 2017-10-03 11:00:01  53.0
2  0    2017-10-04 12:00:01 2017-10-02 10:00:01  50.0
   1    2017-10-05 17:00:01 2017-10-05 15:00:01   2.0
```

The result is not exactly as depicted in your question, but I believe a `MultiIndex` of columns would be a cleaner way of representing your output instead of two trigger columns.

Comment: thanks , this looks like a good idea. Only problem now is: since the data won't find matches for all started and eneded points I need a way how to deal with  null values. At the moment I get the error: 

'ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().' `code`

Comment: @El_Patrón Hmm, assuming these are datetime columns, you _should_ be able to effectively deal with NaN/NaT values - you'll get NaT as the result. If you get something else, then we may need a closer look at your code and data. Most likely your code. Without further context, it would be hard to debug, so see if you can open another question with the data/code that is causing this mess.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, the fields with timestamps are actually formatted as strings, do you think this is causing the error? sorry my knowledge is limited here.

Comment: @El_Patrón Yes. Try this first: `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])`

Comment: Hi @COLDSPEED, thanks for your help, I am still getting some errors. Can it be that the formatting of the code is wrong, may be I should be doing some like: `df.set_index(['id', i, 'trigger']).['timestamp'].unstack().assign(diff=lambda d: d.'started'.sub(d.'ended').dt.total_secounds()/3600)` 
What do you think?